# PSPDFKIT: failed to execute 'compile' on 'webassembly' http status code is not ok

Tags: webassembly, pspdfkit

using PSPDFKit version 2021.5.3 in my local system its working fine, but in our dev environment (https enabled). we are getting error as below:

> failed to execute 'compile' on 'webassembly' http status code is not ok

we can see when downloading a wasm file names something like pspdfkit-77------.wasm failed.

In network tab of browser console we can see response:

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Body buffer overflow","detail":{"errorcode":"protocol.http.TooBigBody"}}}

we also tried to set disableWebAssembly: true, then same error we are getting for ASM file. Although wasm.js is able to load.

In console of browser we are getting in dev env:

> start to download "https://URL_PATH_TO_OUR_APPLICATION/pspdfkit-77XXXXX.wasm download.

& then error

> failed to execute 'compile' on 'webassembly' http status code is not ok

But in local we are getting

> start to download http://localhost:3000/URL_PATH_TO_OUR_APPLICATION/pspdfkit-77XXXXX.wasm download.
>
> Download and Initiation complete ,took:200ms
>
> Native Initialisation complete ,took 294ms.

are we missing anything in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a limitation on the server you're using, which apparently cannot serve files greater than 10MB in size, like the WASM file needed to run PSPDFKit for Web in Standalone mode.